# Fastest way to find the largest frequency of a period at the end of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have the vector `{ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 }`, I want to find out the largest frequency of a period at the end of the vector. In this case, the frequency (curl) is 2, since `112` is repeated twice. And since any period that is repeated at least twice is at most half the vector length, I only need to scan through half the vector.

I am looking for the fastest way to compare parts of the same vector. On recent suggestion, I went over to use `std::equal()`, but I don't know whether this is the best function or if I used it in the fastest possible way.

This is my function currently:

```
vector<int> sequence = someVec;
int curl = 1;
for (int length = 1; length <= sequence.size()/2); ++length) {
    int freq = 1;
    while ((freq + 1) * length <= sequence.size() and std::equal(sequence.end() - (freq + 1) * length, sequence.end() - freq * length, sequence.end() - length)) {
        ++freq;
        if (freq > curl) {
            curl = freq;
        }
    }
}
```

The while-loop does look quite horrendous. Basically, it tries to find matching periods in the end of the vector sequence, and if it finds a repeated period, it checks for how long it is extended. Any suggestions on better implementation or other, faster ways of writing this are really welcome!!

As requested some examples:

Say the vector sequence is `{ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 }` it starts checking how many `2`s are at the end of the vector, which is 1. Next, it checks how many `1, 2`s are at the end, which is 1. Next, it checks `1, 1, 2` and finds that this is repeated 2 times. Thus, the curl is 2.

Say the vector sequence is `{ 2, 2, 2, 2 }` it starts with `2` and finds 4 of these. Next, it checks `2, 2` and finds 2 of these. Thus, the curl is 4.

Since I have to find these curls for sequences up to about a length of 100 million, I really want to squeeze the most out of it. (I do use some mathematical approximation, but this part of the program still takes up about most of the time so I skipped that part).

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please add an input/output example.

Comment: The ultimate answer is write a test using your code and another using `std::equal`. Crank up the optimizer and start timing.

Comment: @user4581301 Actually, I don't think the performance of `equal` is very important here. The algorithm itself could be more efficient perhaps.

Comment: If you carefully read their question requirements and tweak the question to match, you may have a case for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Yes, I linked to how to ask pages on purpose

Comment: How is `j` defined?

Comment: @cigien I join you in the unclear description. It was only later that I saw the `equal` already in the asker's code.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn't know of the existence of Code Review, that looks helpful! I will take a look at it and see if I can get some help there, too! Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, please don't crosspost the question on both sites. Your question seems on-topic here, but you need to make a few changes. First, start off with the problem description, and show your attempt after that. Also, what's the exact logic to stop looking for trailing subvectors?  I think I can figure it out, but you should be explicit.

Comment: @StevenCellist No worries. I cannot stress reading and understanding the posting requirements before asking a question though. They are very skilled and very picky people. They have to be. Performance tuning is all about the details, and if they don't get the details they need, you'll have a sub-optimal experience.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I'm sorry, that was a program-related input. I edited it away right now.
Guys, please be a little patient with me. This is my second question every here, and I need to get used to this.

Comment: No worries, there's no rush :) If your question gets closed, we'll still reopen it once it's fixed.

Comment: I added some extra information. I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, that's much better. One last thing, your title is asking the wrong question. Slicing and comparing are implementation details of the algorithm. Instead, how about something like "What is a better way to find the largest frequency of a period at the end of a vector?"?

Comment: Good idea, I will change it. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: I made a few edits as well. This should give some ideas for how to format your questions.

Comment: So what is the answer for `1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1` ? Is it 3 or 2?  What about `1,2,3,2,3,2,1,2,3,2` ?  Is it 3 or 2?  Are you looking for the frequency of any substring or or of the longest repeated substring?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah for `1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1` it is 2, either `1` or `2,1,1` fulfills the requirement. For `1,2,3,2,3,2,1,2,3,2` the curl is 1, because there is no sub-vector, starting at the end, which is repeated more than once.

Comment: Ahhh.  I see.  I didn't understand that the subsequence was ALWAYS at the end.  That makes it much less hard than the longest repeating subsequence problem. So `1,2,1,2,1` would be 3.

Comment: Yes, always at the end. `1,2,1,2,1` would make 2, because `2, 1` is twice repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now (as you no longer make copies of sub-vectors), almost all the time is spent in comparing values.

I see two independent ways to speed this up: vectorize the compare operation (if your compiler doesn't do it) and parallelize processing of different `length`.

I implemented the multi-threading. Used a vector with 1,000,000 `int`s, the "worst case" with all zeroes (so every compare runs the full length of the sub-vector). A single threaded version took almost 3 minutes, the 12-threads (on my 6-core) - under 30 seconds. Vectorization should save you at least 50% (based on my past experiments). See this for implementation: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-ISA-Extensions/Q-on-memory-comparison-optimization/td-p/1041997

Here is my code (I used globals for simplicity):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

// worst case scenario - all zeroes
std::vector<int> s(1'000'000);
std::mutex m_curl;
unsigned int curl = 1;
std::atomic<int> length;

unsigned int get_curl(int length)
{
  unsigned int local_curl = 1;
  unsigned int freq = 1;
  while ((freq + 1) * length <= s.size() and std::equal(s.end() - (freq + 1) * length, s.end() - freq * length, s.end() - length)) {
    ++freq;
    if (freq > local_curl) {
      local_curl = freq;
    }
  }
  return local_curl;

}

void worker()
{
  unsigned int thread_curl = 1;
  while (true)
  {
    int current_length = length.fetch_sub(1);
    if (current_length <= 0)
      break;
    int local_curl = get_curl(current_length);
    if (local_curl > thread_curl) {
      thread_curl = local_curl;
    }
  }
  // sync access to the curl
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_curl);
    if (thread_curl > curl) {
      curl = thread_curl;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  length = s.size() / 2;
  // create reasonable number of threads
  static const int n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    threads.emplace_back(std::thread(worker));
  // wait for all of them to finish
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    threads[i].join();

  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << std::endl;
  return curl;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I wonder, though, what part did you change for `vectorization`? Because in one type of my script I already use multi-threading since I am doing a ton of smaller sequences at the same time, so they wouldn't profit of multi-threading. (I will do some testing of this script tomorrow)

Comment: @StevenCellist - I just added a link to my answer. You would replace `std::equal` with vectorized `memcmp`. Also note that I've implemented a thread pool, so each thread is utilized to the fullest.

Comment: Do you think multi-threading within multi-threading would still gain an advantage? (by the way, I do have more questions which I feel would not fit here. Is there an option that we could talk private, if you don't mind?)

Comment: @StevenCellist - It makes little sense to have more threads than your hardware can handle. But to use your CPU 100% - you need to have at least that many :) This particular task does a read-only access to the vector, so there is no contention, waits for the mutex, etc. I tried (for the first time) to create a chat room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225134/stdvector-optimization Let's see if it works, or else we'll find another way